# Android observer updated contacts

Tags: android

I have to observe when any contact is added or updated. New contact comes in the end of the table so using  **curser.moveToLast();**  I can get new added contact from contact table inside the observer but if i update any contact how it will be possible to get the ID of that contact. Please tell me the possible ways.

Answer (score 0):

At last i got a way. Please let me know if there is any better way.

This class will observe every add/Update entry in contacts table :-

```
public class ObserverReceiver extends ContentObserver {

private static final String TAG = "ObserverReceiver";

private Context context;

public ObserverReceiver(Handler handler, Context context) {
    super(handler);

    this.context = context; 
}

// will be called when database get change
@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
    super.onChange(selfChange);

    Log.d(TAG, "Observer has been started..");
    long currentTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // Contacts Cursor
    Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    // Check which contact is added or updated
    if (cur != null) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            // Get contact added/updated timestamp but CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP 
            //is added in API 18

            String timeStampStr = cur
                    .getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP));

            long timeStamp = Long.parseLong(timeStampStr);

            // Check if any contact id added/updated with in 5 second
            // you can reduce the time it take hardly 1 or 2 sec in 
            // processing so i hape you will get the exact entry every time
            if (timeStamp > (currentTimeStamp - 5000))
                // Get new/updated contact detail here
                String id = cur.getString(cur .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String contactName = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        }
    }
    cur.close();
}
```

}

:)

Comment: Your can do it much more effective if you keep the last time stamp you used to look for changes, and the next query selection you use can be:  ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP + " > theLastTimestampIUsed"