# Android contacts sync in background

Tags: android

---

I want to show the contacts whoever using my app. I know this is an old one but nothing satisfies me. I'm already using the method that gets all the contacts from phone and send to server and checking the available contacts who all are 
using my app then return to my app.

Finally, it will save into the local database. But the problem is when adding new contact we have to sync again. For that time it will take more time and other functionality may become slow.

What I need is when I open the app at first time it should sync all the contacts and then it should monitor the changes like add, delete and update of the contacts then only it should check the changed contact.

[I refers this blog](http://blogs.quovantis.com/syncing-contacts-with-an-android-application-2/), but there is no proper code. So many files are missed. How can i sync contacts?

Comment: checkout this library https://github.com/shahbazhashmi/contact-picker

Comment: I already using contact picker. But i need the syncing concept like whatsapp, hike

Comment: Hi Dinesh, you cannot expect whole code from scratch on SO. Try on Github. I suggest you to first build your logic using flowchart and algorithms including all your edge cases. And for syncing you can use work manager.

Comment: you can use a ContentObserver on the Contacts.CONTENT_URI table, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24968901/android-observer-updated-contacts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally,I have done with this [library](https://github.com/6thsolution/EasyAppleSyncAdapter).